# To Use or Not to Use Data.Map

Tags: data-structures, haskell

I'm currently working on a Haskell API. The latter provides some functions that currently take a *list of lists* as input, i.e. `[(String,[(String, Double)])]`.

For visualization purposes, here's a sample of the *list of lists* mentioned above:

```
[
    ("A",   [
                ("I1", 1),
                ("I2", 2),
            ]
    ),
    ("B",   [
                ("I1", 3),
            ]
    )
]
```

I've defined some *private* helper functions. One helper function will search for specific entries in this list (`Data.List.find` = `O(n)`); another one will perform intersections; and another function will transform the list presented above to the following one:

```
[
    ("I1",  [
                ("A", 1),
                ("B", 3),
            ]
    ),
    ("I2",  [
                ("A", 2),
            ]
    )
]
```

The function that performs the transformation uses `Data.Map`, since it offers some functions that simplify that process a lot, like `Data.Map.unionWith` and `Data.Map.insertWith`. Well, since the transformation function had to call `Data.Map.fromList` and `Data.Map.toList`, I thought it would be nice to have a *map of maps* instead of a *list of lists* from the beginning. And so I changed my sample input to match the *map of maps* requirement.

Again, for visualization purposes, here's the list from above as a *map of maps*:

```
Map.fromList [
    ("A",   Map.fromList [
                ("I1", 1),
                ("I2", 2),
            ]
    ),
    ("B",   Map.fromList [
                ("I1", 3),
            ]
    )
]
```

Thanks to this step my code lost a few lines, and thanks to `Data.Map.lookup`, finding a desired now only takes `O(log n)` time.

Nonetheless, I'm currently asking myself if this really is a good solution? Is a *map of maps* the way to go? Or should the transformation function work with `Data.Map.fromList` and `Data.Map.toList`, and let the rest work with *list of lists*? Or better yet, is there a data structure that is more suitable for this kind of work?

I'm really looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Did your lookups actually get faster (in wall-clock time), or did you improve the algorithmic complexity?  While alg. complexity is an important consideration, there are other considerations.  If you only have a few elements (maybe <10?), the list of lists is probably the most efficient.

Comment: John: thanks for your input. I was using `Data.List.find` to search for an element. It's a recommendations API, so it should be able to handle quite an amount of data.

Comment: John: By re-reading my previous comment, I noticed that I didn't answer your first question. Sorry for that. I improved the algorithmic complexity, since `Data.List.find` takes `O(n)` time, and I replaced it with `Data.Map.lookup`, which will run in `O(log n)` time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialization of the map-of-maps still only takes `O(n)`.

Consider the list-of-lists first.

Let's say the outer list is [ a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>p</sub> ], and each inner item is a<sub>j</sub> = ( l<sub>j</sub>, [ b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, ..., b<sub>q<sub>j</sub></sub> ]).  Then construction of the list-of-lists takes O(n = ∑<sub>j=1</sub><sup>p</sup> q<sub>j</sub>).

Initializing an inner map takes m<sub>j</sub>. = O(q<sub>j</sub>).  Initializing the map-of-maps takes O(∑<sub>j=1</sub><sup>p</sup> m<sub>j</sub>) = O(n).

Comment: rampion: +1, and thanks for your excellent answer. In this case I can continue to work with `Data.Map`, since the initialization of both structures runs in `O(n)`, and `Data.Map` provides the better suited functions for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

This smells like graphs and edges.  One slightly different approach, which may or may not work is to rework your problem so instead of `[(String,[(String,Double)])]` you simply operate on 2-tuples of strings.  Then you have `[((String, String), Double)]` and the resulting map is of type `Data.Map.Map (String, String) Double`.

Alternatively, if the space of string keys is limited, and can thus be mapped efficiently into machine ints, look into using an IntMap.  Same semantics as a map except that the keys MUST be machine ints (Int32 or Int64).  Will have much better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this depends on your actual data, but maybe you could use a Multimap instead? There are implementations floating around (e.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Holumbus-Distribution/0.0.1.1/doc/html/Holumbus-Data-MultiMap.html ) but I didn't try them out.

Comment: Landei: +1, and thanks for your pointer, too. I'm going to have a more detailed look at it. From the description it sounds quite promising and well-suited for my use case.